# React native IOS keyboard short cuts is not working

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

for some reason the iOS keyboard isn’t triggering keyboard shortcuts on my RN input fields. For example, double space should insert a period. Any ideas what could be the reason?

Comment: are you using the real device or iOS simulator?

Comment: @akshaygore real device